# ARM template for deploying and disabling Azure Stream Analytics Service

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-stream-analytics

Is there a way we can deploy the stream analytics jobs in disabled mode through ARM template?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way to do it. There is no attribute to create it in stopped state for ARM but deployment scripts are used to extend ARM templates.

You should add a section like below to your ARM template. Also, don't forget to add dependOn condition to Azure Analytics Jobs otherwise, it might try to stop a non-existing job..

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts",
  "apiVersion": "2020-10-01",
  "name": "runBashWithOutputs",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "kind": "AzureCLI",
  "identity": {
    "type": "UserAssigned",
    "userAssignedIdentities": {
      "[parameters('identity')]": {
      }
    }
  },
  "properties": {
    "forceUpdateTag": "[parameters('utcValue')]",
    "AzCliVersion": "2.15.0",
    "timeout": "PT30M",
    "arguments": "'foo' 'bar'",
    "scriptContent": "result=$(az stream-analytics job stop --resource-group $1);echo $result | jq -c '{Result: map({id: .id})}' > $AZ_SCRIPTS_OUTPUT_PATH",
    "cleanupPreference": "OnSuccess",
    "retentionInterval": "P1D"
  }
}
```

You can check more in their documentation, [Use deployment scripts in ARM templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template)